# Is there any way to read a remote MS access database in rails website deployed on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ms-access, heroku, sequel, ngrok

I have a rails website deployed on Heroku. I want to read the Microsoft access database file which is shared by the windows cloud machine using ngrok. I have tried to use [sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel) gem. I run this code

```
require "sequel"
Sequel.ado(conn_string: 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=https://file_link_path;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;')
```

I get this error on the second line
[image]
After adding gem win32ole in the gem file I get this error
[image]
Now I am out of Ideas. Please help me out
Thank you in advance

Comment: You won't be able to use any Windows-specific code on Heroku since it doesn't run Windows. That means OLE is out. There are third-party drivers that might work, but you'd have to try them. (Aside: this sounds like a _terrible_ idea. I'd strongly avoid connecting to any database you're hosting inside a firewall and exposing via `ngrok`. And if at all possible I'd get rid of Access entirely, though I recognize that that may be easier said than done.)

Comment: Yup, the short answer to this question is: No. The long answer is yes, anything is possible, but you will encounter tons of obstacles and after overcoming all of them it will likely still be an unstable abomination.

Comment: @Chris if you are stuck with Access I would imagine that a workable solution would be to create a API server on a Windows platform (Azure?) and let it communicate with the DB? The Rails app then communicates with the API via HTTP.

Comment: 1) Upsize the database to SQL server. 2) Host on Azure. For your own sanity, remove Access from the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Access is file based - not service based. So, you need read/write of the file and you need a windows compatible file system. You can't use http or even ftp. Those are not direct file read/write protocols. So not only do you need direct file read/write ability, but you ALSO must use a compatible windows file networking. So, say if  you place that file on a Linux box, then you need to run samba to produce a windows compatible file networking connection, and THEN and ONLY then can you directly open that file for read/write.

this is not really any different then opening a word file, or even a text file. You do NOT connect to a text file. you can certainly pull + donwload that file from the souce and THEN read/process the file local. (assumign you have the JET or ACE data engine code local to then open + read the file.

So, a horse is a horse is a horse.

And

A file is a file is a file.

You don't connect to a text file anymore then to a Excel file or in this case  Access file. There is no such concept of a http connection. As noted, you can use somthing like say FTP or a http download of the file to where your code is running, and then at that point you are free to open + read that local file. But you don't connect to a "file" nor can you connect to a file based database like JET/ACE. (same as sqlite - it is a local file based system - not a service running on the other end). So this is really just a file sitting in some folder. And thus to use that file over a network? Well, either you copy the file local or you can attempt to OPEN the file OVER the network. But that as noted means you need the software (in this case Access data engine) running local and that open command over the network would require a VPN for this to work - not some socket connection and not some http connection - those protocols can't open + read a file - they can certainly open + read the file local, and then perhaps dish out data via http, but you can't open that file remote anymore then you can open files on amazon.com servers either - they are behind the web site.